# Meaning of $B_\epsilon(x)\setminus\{x\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does Carothers mean when, referring to open balls, he writes $B_\epsilon(x) \setminus \{x\}$?

Does this refer to an open ball minus a singleton set, $x$ ?

Why not just write $B_\epsilon(x) \setminus x $ ?

Comment: $\setminus$ is the difference between **sets**. $\{x\}$ is a set, but $x$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because $x$ and $\{x\}$ are different things, and $\setminus$ operates on sets. $A\setminus B$ means "The set of all elements which appear in the set $A$ but don't appear in the set $B$". If you write
$$
B_{\epsilon}(x)\setminus x
$$
then that means "The open ball around $x$, except all the points which are elements of the set $x$". That doesn't really make sense. $x$ isn't a set (one can get pedantic about whether $x$ is a set, but I'm electing not to for simplicity).

On the other hand, if you write
$$
B_{\epsilon}(x)\setminus \{x\}
$$
then that means "The open ball around $x$, except all the points which are elements of the set $\{x\}$" which is exactly the "punctured" ball the author seems to be after.